# Java Out of heap, Stack Overflow error

Tags: java, json, jackson, apache-camel, pojo

I have a problem in implementing a Camel Route, where I call a URl and convert the JSON Response into Pojo. I use Camel-Jackson.

Connection establishes with status 200.

But I get

```
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:541)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:644)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
caused because of java.lang.StackOverflowError.
```

Here is a sample code

```
from("direct:start")
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET"))
    .to("URL")
    .process(new Processor() {
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            int responseCode = exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, Integer.class);
            System.out.println(exchange.getIn().getBody());
            System.out.println(responseCode);
        }
    })
    .marshal(cont)
    .process(new MyProcessor())
    .end();
```

`cont` is the Jackson data format. I increased my heap memory to 1024 M. But still it's showing Stack overflow error. But the Json file is just 26 Kb. I used http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/‎ site to create the Pojos for the json.

Comment: You increase the stack size with the '-Xss<number>m' flag.

Comment: yes i did. I cant increase more than 1GB. i have my internal memory occupied for 2.2 gb. my total occupiable space in ram is 3.25 gb. But i guess the program demands more..

Comment: If that is the case then I think JonK:s answer below is a correct analysis. It definitely sounds like run-away recursion.

Comment: You absolutely **should not** be giving your thread stack that much space. The default setting should be more than enough for the vast majority of applications. If I needed anything more than `-Xss128k` for my thread stack I would be taking a *serious* look at my code to see what I should be changing to avoid needing that much.

Comment: my bad people. i gave marshal instead of unmarshal(). Sorry for wasting your valuable time. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, a large or endless chain of recursive method calls are the main culprit of `StackOverflowError`s, although they are by no means the *only* cause. One of your other issues is that your thread stack size may be set to a low number (if you're seeing a `StackOverflowError` but only have a small stack trace this is probably what's happening).

If your stack trace only has a small number of frames, check to see if your JVM has the `-Xss` launch option set. If it does, you may need to change it to something larger, if it doesn't then try adding `-Xss256k` to your JVM's launch options (the default is `-Xss128k` for Windows x64 machines). This can be increased further if need be.

If your stack trace is pretty large, then it's more likely to be recursive method calls. You should be able to tell from the trace itself which method(s) are being recursively called, and can then look to correcting the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your JSON Java class, if it contains a recursive cycle that may blow up your application. If this is the case add `@JsonIgnore` to the relevant attribute to break the cycle.